# Writing a formula to count how many times each date appears in a set of date ranges

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, date

Given an Excel spreadsheet with two columns:

`Creation Date`, `Closure Date`

For each date covered by all date ranges over all columns, I want to know how many records cover each day.

For example:

```
Record Creation   Closure
  1    01/01/2001 01/01/2001
  2    01/01/2001 03/01/2001
  3    01/01/2001 02/01/2001
  4    03/01/2001 03/01/2001
```

Given the above data, the results should be as follows:

```
01/01/2001: 3 (Records 1,2,3)
02/01/2001: 2 (Records 2,3)
03/01/2001: 2 (Records 2,4)
```

I only need to know the counts per day; and I'm happy to start out with a new column containing each date, rather than expecting the formula to calculate the date-range also.

Comment: Coming from [PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/166802/80010)... just curious isn’t this more a regular SO question? Never used super user so might be a silly question

Comment: Yeah, it was  bit borderline for me too - I suspect it could suit either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a column (E) containing all the dates:

`=(COUNTIFS(Table1[Creation Date],"<="&E2,Table1[Closure Date],">="&E2))`